# Power BI does not create Dataset automatically with Python and R functions

Tags: python, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I've been facing a weird behavior on Power BI, as a new User I'm trying to work on a simple table by creating a Plot for a specific value. However Power BI is not creating the standard nomination "DATASET" for the Dataframe, just show as a null value. As result I got stuck to keep my transformation ahead.
I've already installed Anaconda3 and the last Power BI update (Version: 2.96.901.0 64-bit), also tried different regional settings, but nothing changed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB2M1.png)

Could anyone help me to overcome that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and still not directly working when clicking on python visual scripts...the only workaround I found to work is by establishing the fields you want to plot in the table visualization and then clicking on the python visual script, which in return will add them in the dataset.